# Receiving unexpected output when indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want my code to do is take an input file and read a list of integers from the file (e.g. `40`, `34`, `14`, `52`), I then want it to save these integers to a list then display them in reverse by iterating through the list backwards using a negative index.

```
fileobject = open(filename,'r')
contents = fileobject.read()
fileobject.close()

contentlength = (-len(contents)-1)
for i in range(-1,contentlength,-1):
    print(contents[i])
```

The code runs and prints out my numbers in reverse order but it prints them out with strange spacing like so. Here is example output if the file contains the numbers `40`, `34`, `14`, and `52`:

```
2
5

4
1

4
3

0
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that you're never splitting up your input numbers. You're iterating over the text of the input file and writing it back out one character at a time (in reverse order). If you want the numbers to be kept intact (e.g. `"40"`, rather than `"0"` followed by `"4"`) and for the spaces in the input not to appear in the output, you'll need to split up the input string before you go about writing it out in reverse.

Try:

```
with open(filename) as f:  # a with statement handles closing the file automatically
    text = f.read()        # read file as a single string

contents = text.split()    # form a list by splitting the text on whitespace
```

The rest of your code (doing the output loop) can then work as it does currently. However, a slightly more "Pythonic" solution would be to use a `for` loop over a reverse iterator on the list, rather than using `range` and indexing:

```
for num_string in reversed(contents):
    print(num_string)
```

Note that the "numbers" handled by this code are not actually `int` objects. They remain strings throughout. If you actually needed to do some mathematical operations on the values, rather than just printing them, you'd probably want to use the `int` constructor to turn the strings into actual Python numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had completely forgotten about the split feature. It all works as expected now.